Vue3 + Vuetify3 custom markdown component for blog post
Using Vue3 and Vuetify3. But happy with any solution. I'm currently doing a component that will allow for typing text and images for a blog entry. The idea is that the user can type their blog entry in a  and attach images to that.
There's basically two problems here:
1- Since  does not allow to attach images inside, I think I'd need to add another input to attach the images, and then reference them with some kind of markdown, like [image1] will reference to image with ID 1.
2- Once the text is written, how can I transform that into a rendered HTML? For example, the user will type like this:

And then images should be displayed in the same row, with a custom class, for example:

The images for the sample UI I'm adding them like this:
      <span>Lorem ...</span>
      <div class="image-container d-flex justify-center align-center">
        <div
          v-for="i in 3"
          :key="i"
          class="square-image"
          :style="{
            backgroundImage: `url(${dummy})`,
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center'
          }"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <span>Lorem ...</span>

After this, I'd like to be able to render this text+images as a blog post in a separate component, by passing the text+images to it.
Basically, I'd like to know if this approach of generating an ID per picture and referencing with some markdown is the best solution. And also how to render the text, taking into account that there might images in between and should be set in a different row (up to 3 images).
Thanks!

Best and most secure way is to use a server as a middleware to sanitize and host all of this while sending the generated HTML.

I'd recommend TipTap Editor. It does all of this almost out of the box, and can be extended with custom nodes up to Vue components.
